# datamapper - query over an object property

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

using datamapper with ruby. Suppose i have a model called Post:

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String, length: 255
  property :category_ids, Object
end

Post.create(name: 'My post', category_ids: [1,2,3])

Post.all(category_ids: [1])
=> []
Post.all(category_ids: [1,2,3])
=> []
```

It's possible to query over Object properties?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Range`. `Post.all(category_ids: (1..3))`